# Spark reading all records when I try to find max of partition field

Tags: apache-spark, max, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I think I don't understand a thing of spark. I have a table partitioned by 'partition_date' maybe with around 10 partitions, but with a lot of records inside each one.

When I try to find the max of this field, why spark seems to be evaluating all records in table if It knows that is the partition field. Intuitive it will be only evaluate this 10 strings of the partition field and return the max.

I've made a fast approach using 'show partitions' but I'm interested in this behaviour,

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

***Partitions are the chunks of data (not the data) and spark query gets executed on data.***

Spark will use `partition_date` to create `partitions` and `distribute` the data into those `partitions` accordingly. It will not query `partitions` but, the data in those partitions, so the query `max` will run on the actual data.